# Adding new column field with value to existing delta table

Tags: azure-databricks

1. New column added with values from source side. On the landing side(sink) i have stage table which is receiving the new data.
2. On the processing side i am merging the stage with process data(final table) with condition.
3. How can i add new column to the existing final delta table from stage data.
4. All process is currently running as job.

I know there should be merge schema for new field but not sure about detail steps. Can anyone guide with detailed step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results**:

*For demo , I created delta table in this location  `/mnt/defaultDatalake/KK1`*

[image]

***Now, I performed the merge operation updated and added a new column field with the value into the existing delta table in that location using below code.***

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

spark.read.format("delta").load('/mnt/defaultDatalake/KK1')\
  .withColumn("Recovered", lit('USA'))\
  .write\
  .format("delta")\
  .mode("overwrite")\
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true")\
  .save('/mnt/defaultDatalake/KK1')
```

[image]

***Now you can check , I got new column called `Recovered`.***

[image]